# R parallel rbindlist does not work

Tags: r

I have a function that uses rbindlist, and I would like to call that function using parLapply. Simplified version below:

```
func <- function(x){
  df1 <- data.frame(a = c(x,2), b = c(3,4))
  df2 <- data.frame(a = c(x,2), b = c(4,4))
  rbindlist(list(df1,df2))
}

cl <- makeCluster(getOption('cl.cores', detectCores()))
tmp <- parLapply(cl,c(1,2),func)
stopCluster(cl)
```

However, I get an error that says:

Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "rbindlist"

Comment: I can't find `rbindlist` either. What library is it in?

Comment: Did you initialize that library on your cluster nodes? `clusterEvalQ(cl, library(data.table)) `?

Comment: yeah you might have to initialize or just add ```library(data.table)``` in the actual function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using other libraries with `parlapply`, make sure you properly load them on each node. you can do

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(data.table))
```

Before running your commands, or include

```
require(data.table)
```

in your function.